# wp_list_pages broken in 3.5?

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

I'm trying to list all the pages of custom post type, but using:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'white_paper',
'depth' => -1
);
wp_list_pages($args); 

?>
```

Doesn't work. I can't seem to be able to even list the pages of the post_type of 'post' nor include pages by ids with the 'include' parameter. I've tried this locally on a fresh install and on my staging website. Running on 3.5.2 and 3.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Is the custom post type flagged as 'hierarchical' or is it being treated as a normal 'post'? The wp_list_pages function only works with hierarchical custom post types:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

(look under the 'post_type' parameter)

Comment: Holy crap. that was it thanks for saving me more hours of headache.